# How do I extract prices from a string after a label using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

My string could look like this:

```
Rental DurationPrice60-day$47.8090-day$56.23120-day$60.92
```

or

```
Rental DurationPrice90-day$47.80180-day$56.23
```

or

any combination of:

```
30-day and/or 60-day and/or 90-day and/or 180-day
```

I'd like to capture the prices that follow these time frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex captures the prices following all *nn-day* fields.

```
/(?:30|60|180)-day\$(\d+\.\d\d)/
```

Use it as

```
prices = "Rental DurationPrice60-day$47.8090-day$56.23120-day$60.92"
prices.scan(/(?:30|60|180)-day\$(\d+\.\d\d)/)
```

to fetch all prices into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a more complicated regex, I'd go with `String.scan` and let it walk through the string:

```
'Rental DurationPrice60-day$47.8090-day$56.23120-day$60.92'.scan(/\$[\d.]+/)
[
    [0] "$47.8090",
    [1] "$56.23120",
    [2] "$60.92"
]
```

If you don't want the currency indicator you can post-process the values, stripping off the first character:

```
'Rental DurationPrice60-day$47.8090-day$56.23120-day$60.92'.scan(/\$[\d.]+/).map{ |s| s[1..-1] }
[
    [0] "47.8090",
    [1] "56.23120",
    [2] "60.92"
]
```

Or use a tiny different regex with the `flatten` method:

```
'Rental DurationPrice60-day$47.8090-day$56.23120-day$60.92'.scan(/\$([\d.]+)/).flatten
[
    [0] "47.8090",
    [1] "56.23120",
    [2] "60.92"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will capture all the prices: `(?:\d{2,}-day\$(\d+\.\d{2}))`